# Setting height and d-flex together on a .card-header doesn't work when .card-body content is overflowing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am using `bootstrap` `cards` with following styles:

1. `height` and `width` of `.card` are set to be `500px`
2. `.card-header` is flexbox to align its content `left`, `right` and `center` as shown in code.
3. `.card-body` is overflowing with content so I have set it to be `overflow-y: scroll`

**Problem**:

Given above style constraints, if I want to set `height` of `.card-header` (example `100px`), its not working. However this `height` setting will work fine if I remove flexbox from .`card-header`

I would like to know why this problem is occuring.

**Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style>
    .card{
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }
    .card-header{
        height: 100px;/*remove this and header height will be 100px*/
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .card-body{
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .border-red{
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
<body>

<div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-header border-red ">
        <div>left</div>
        <div>center</div>
        <div>right</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Card-header is a card's flex item so we have to work with its flex property. Try this:

**Edit to explain why the following code works:**

- `.card` is flex box with `flex-direction:column`
- `.card` is having two flex-item: `.card-header` and `.card-body`
- If sum total of the two flex item is less than the height of `flexbox`, stated problem won't occur. But the moment it surpasses `flexbox` height, `flex-shrink` property of both flex-items come into play and shrinks the height of both of the items in equal proportion.
- Below code sets `flex-shrink` for `.card-header` `0`, meaning its height won't change when the height of `.card-body` increases (beyond overflow)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style>
    .card{
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }
    .card-header{
        flex: 1 0 100px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .card-body{
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .border-red{
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
<body>

<div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-header border-red ">
        <div>left</div>
        <div>center</div>
        <div>right</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
        <div>overflow</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1. But can you explain why its happening, as I have asked in the question? Normally I wouldn't have any problem with the setting height of flexbox container.

Comment: To be more specific, why doesn't height work while flex basis does?

Comment: @dasfdsa Chapeau, man. Couldn't have said it better myself! +1 to your edit! ;)